# Extended command by regexp?

Tags: emacs, icicles

In Emacs - is there a way I can search an extended command by regex right in the minibuffer? That is - I want to filter commands by regexp and then choose the one I need using IDO or Icicles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always suspected that `Icicles` provdies that.

```
M-x <command-regexp> [PageUp/PageDown]
```

to browse the commands mathching regexp, and

```
M-x <command-regexp> [Shift-Tab]
```

to see the list of commands matching regexp. More [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions).

Comment: [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi_M-x) is a description of `M-x` in [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).  See also what **`C-h k M-x`** tells you.

Answer (score 2):

When using ido you can turn on regexp matching by pressing `C-t`. I use `smex` and `ido` together and it works beautifully.

Comment: It seems like You can't use `smex` with `Icicles`.

Answer (score 2):

While they are not regexps, the default completion mechanism accepts a * to stand for "anything", so you can do `M-x foo*bar ?` and it will list all the commands whose name looks like "...foo...bar...".

Comment: Cool. But `Icicles` overrides this behavior.